# awk to convert "{(linefeed)" to just "{"

Tags: awk

I would like use awk to convert "{(linefeed)" to just "{"

I tried w/o success

```
awk '{gsub("{\n", "{")} input >output;
```

any sensible descriptive solutions...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GNU awk for multi-char RS to let you read the whole file at once:

```
awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/{\n/, "{")} 1' input >output
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, unlike perl, the record separator does not appear in the record.

If that last character on the line is an open brace, print without a newline, else print with a newline.

```
awk '/{$/ {printf "%s", $0; next} 1' file
```

or,

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, /{$/ ? "" : ORS}' file
```